# Strange syntax construct - operator () applied to a typedef compiles successfully with VS2015

Tags: c++

Why the following code successfully compiles with VS2015 without errors and warnings? And what is "IsInternetESCEnabledFunc()" ?

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef VOID
(WINAPI
    *IsInternetESCEnabledFunc)(
        OUT BOOL
        );

IsInternetESCEnabledFunc IsInternetESCEnabled_lb;

int main()
{
    auto something = IsInternetESCEnabledFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a function pointer, and `()` initiates to call that function pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a temporary `IsInternetESCEnabledFunc` -- a value-initialized, i.e. null, function pointer.

Comment: You can find it detailed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) (4th variant). The fact that it is a function pointer is irrelevant, we are in the general `T()` case.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky as does `std::string()` or `YourOwnClassType()`, if that looks more familiar :)

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` defines a function pointer: a pointer to a function that looks like

```
VOID WINAPI function(OUT BOOL)
```

The function the pointer points to is then called (with `()` just like a function).

Without any further assignment it's probably a random value (or nullptr depending on where you define the variable) so the call will cause some random crashes.

Comment: You cannot call a type :)

Comment: @Quentin Reworded it :)

Comment: I meant that you fell into the same trap as OP -- `IsInternetESCEnabledFunc` is a function pointer *type*, not a function pointer. The actual pointer is `IsInternetESCEnabled_lb` but is not used.

Comment: @Quentin now I see what you mean... it's not actually the variable that is used...

Comment: @Quentin That explains why it can be assigned to `auto` and be "called" without a parameter :)